# Magento 1.9 - Cookies issue on Safari

Tags: magento-1.9

I'm having an issue regarding the checkout my online shop using Safari. When the user clicks to proceed with the checkout, the message that appears before the payment gateway redirection is: invalid session or temporary cookies disabled.

Note that this issue happens only at safari, at firefox and chrome is all ok. Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: Same to me! The _Enable Cookies_ page view grows insanely since january 23th only for Safari. Could it be related to the [last upgrade](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT208475)?

Comment: Hi,  problem solved! This worked for me: Go to System -> Configuration -> Web -> Session Cookie Management and set “Use HTTP Only” to no. Simple as that! Found at: http://howlingwolf.de/blog/2011/12/magento-cookie-fuckup-chromesafari-webkit-engine-stuff/

Comment: We had that exact same problem and the - fix session cookie management appears to have worked.